# Matlab output is the expression and not a number

Tags: matlab

I am trying to learn the Secant Method of finding roots of a function.

While reading through the web I encountered [this](http://www.engineershandbook.net/secant-method/) site and tried its code:

```
a=input('enter function:','s');
f=inline(a)
x(1)=input('enter first guess: ');
x(2)=input('enter second guess: ');
n=input('enter tolerance: ');
iteration=0;
for i=3:1000
   x(i) = x(i-1) - (f(x(i-1)))*((x(i-1) - x(i-2))/(f(x(i-1)) - f(x(i-2))));
    iteration=iteration+1;
    if abs((x(i)-x(i-1))/x(i))*100<n
        root=x(i)
        iteration=iteration
        break
    end
end
```

However, when the function ends the iteration and is to display *root=x(i)* all I get is the entire expression instead of a number. Following the sites example, instead of getting the number 4 I get two multidigit numbers divided by each other (A/B) which, when put in matlab, gives me the result 4.
Why is this?

Is it a configuration problem or is the code flawed in some way?

Thank you!
Sincerely, RKrogh!

Comment: RKrogh, when I execute the code and enter the inputs exactly as given on your link site, I get "
root =

    4.0000


iteration =

     6". Could you edit your question to include your keyboard inputs please?

Comment: Okay, I guess this is a question about configuration then. Thank you a lot @danny!

Comment: It works just fine in Octave too. BTW, `inline` will be removed in a future release, see http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/inline.html.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, @am304. I still haven't figured out why that version and configs of matlab wrote the entire expression but running the code on my home computer gave me the numerical output.

Comment: I do not have a problem. Are you sure that the equation you entered have a root? The expression is printed in the command window since you have left out the semicolon. However, since you do only print iteration and root in case they exist, you will not get an output in the case that the root is not found. I know this is only a test, but for both testing and for the entire function there is a good idea to have an output even if the root is not found. That could be NaN or whatever you want.